# Marketing Cloud - private domain on multiple business units

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a full SAP package setup on one business unit and would like to use that same Sender Profile in a different business unit.

It looks like I can just add the from email addresses using the subdomain to the 'From Address Management' and verify it via email link and than use that for the Sender Profile.

Is there any known issues this could cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an unrecognized domain, the system will send the confirmation email directly to the email address added (with your sending subdomain). As far as I know, there is no way to access emails sent to a private domain used for sending in SFMC.

I would recommend making this request through Salesforce support, who should be able to add the private domain as an verified entry in the From Address Management for that business unit. They can also have entire the SAP replicated onto another business unit should you wish.